# How to do custom rounding of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, rounding

Suppose I want to round numbers that have [mantissa](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html) greater than 0.3 'up' and those below 'down'.

How can I do it in Java?

The only thing that came to my mind was `Math.round()`, but I can't seem to make it follow a certain rule.

Comment: try Math.round(x + 0.2), i.e. just provide the offset to the regular rounding point

Comment: Thanks it worked! But can you please elaborate how could it do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.floor(x+0.7)` should do it.

This should work for an arbitrary mantissa. Just add the offset to the next integer to your value and round down.
The rounding is done by floor. Here is what the java API says to floor:

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that
>   is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical
>   integer.

This solution is similar to the one from @Thomas Stets, but imho it is easier to understand since rounding is done in only one direction.