# How to customize the form of rounding

Tags: java, math, decimal, rounding, digits

My question may seem simple, but still can not get something that works.
I need to customize the Math.round rounding format or something to make it work as follows:

If the number is 1.6 he should round to 1, if greater than or equal to 1.7 should round to 2.0 . And so to all other decimal results with # .6
The way I'm doing the 1.6 being rounded to 2 shall be rounded to 1.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: [How to do custom rounding of numbers in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976081/how-to-do-custom-rounding-of-numbers-in-java)
May be this will be help full

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
double threshold = 0.7;
Math.round(x - threshold + 0.5);
```

Comment: Cool answer. But it doesn't beyond this precision.. 1.6999999

Comment: @ArcticLord Thank you so much. This is simple and exactly what I need works perfectly and i just need the precision to 2 decimal places.
Very very Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that takes a `double` variable as input and returns the integer based on the first digit after the point. For instance, you could convert the input to a `String` and delimit it at the decimal point. Then check if the first digit after the point is less or greater than 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(x + 0.6);
```

It possibly may solve your question.