# How to round numbers to certain intervals?

Tags: java, android, numbers

How to round a number as follows:

If it's 7.3 I want the rounding to go up to 7.5 , but if it's 7.77 I want it to go up to 8

Another example is if it's 13.1 I want it to go to 13.5, but if it's 13.9 I want it to go to 14.

This in Java-Android, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[These](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) are the common Rounding Modes for Java.

But you can make something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455061/how-to-customize-rounding-mode-in-java), and create your own custom rounding strategy.

---

Something like:

```java
static BigDecimal myRound(BigDecimal value) {
    BigInteger fractPart = value.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).movePointRight(bd.scale()).abs().toBigInteger();
    
    if (fractPart.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(3) == 0) {
        // change value to .5
    } else {
        // change value to .77
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: add more information here rather than just referring to other sites